# Firebase custom auth error: `The custom token format is incorrect`

Tags: firebase, firebase-authentication

I'm trying to implement authentication with custom generated tokens.

These tokens are generated on the authentication server when authentication is successful.

I then pass said token to my Firebase app with

`firebase.auth().signInWithCustomToken(token)`

and get a `400` response with this error message:

`The custom token format is incorrect`

As I said these tokens are generated independently from Firebase and, from [reading here](https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/server/create-custom-tokens), I think that's my problem.

My question: is it possible to set custom token authentication without setting up the service account private key on the authentication server?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is no way to mint a custom authentication token without knowing the private key and service account of the project. The private key is used to sign the token, so that the server can verify its validity. Allowing to mint tokens without that would be a huge security risk.

Comment: But frank, if someone intercepts an existing custom token and sets it on their own made version of the app(since dburl and apikey are anyway exposed on web), will the FirebaseAuth not auto refresh the said token?